MySql: load data from a .csv file which has no trailing commas/delimiters
I am trying to load data from a .csv file into mysql table
these are the contents of my .csv file (here rows are formatted for better readability, the file is not formatted like this)
Date       ,Band             ,ConcertName                                   ,Country ,City   ,Location                   ,LocationAddress
2023-05-28 ,Ozzy Osbourne    ,No More Tours 2 - Special Guest: Judas Priest ,Germany ,Berlin ,Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin ,"Mercedes-Platz 1, 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain"
2023-05-08 ,Elton John       ,Farewell Yellow Brick Road Tour 2023          ,Germany ,Berlin ,Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin ,"Mercedes-Platz 1 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain"
2023-05-26 ,Hans Zimmer Live ,Europe Tour 2023                              ,Germany ,Berlin ,Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin ,"Mercedes-Platz 1, 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain"
2023-07-07 ,Depeche Mode     ,Memento Mori World Tour 2023                  ,Germany ,Berlin ,Olympiastadion Berlin      ,"Olympischer Platz 3, 14053 Berlin-Charlottenburg"

And this is the query that is used to load the data
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
    INFILE 'temp.csv' 
    INTO TABLE concerts2 
    FIELDS 
        TERMINATED BY ',' 
        ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES 
        TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS 
    
    (`Date`,`Band`,`ConcertName`,`Country`,`City`,`Location`,`LocationAddress`)
;

The query is successfully executed but the data is not read correctly from the .csv file.
mysql> select * from concerts2;
+----+------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+--------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | Date       | Band          | ConcertName                                   | Country | City   | Location                   | LocationAddress
                              |
+----+------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+--------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 2023-05-28 | Ozzy Osbourne | No More Tours 2 - Special Guest: Judas Priest | Germany | Berlin | Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin | "Mercedes-Platz 1, 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain"
2023-05-08,Elton John,Farewell Yellow Brick Road To |
+----+------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+--------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

But if I add trailing commas to each row in the .csv file
Date       ,Band             ,ConcertName                                   ,Country ,City   ,Location                   ,LocationAddress                                    ,
2023-05-28 ,Ozzy Osbourne    ,No More Tours 2 - Special Guest: Judas Priest ,Germany ,Berlin ,Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin ,"Mercedes-Platz 1, 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain"    ,
2023-05-08 ,Elton John       ,Farewell Yellow Brick Road Tour 2023          ,Germany ,Berlin ,Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin ,"Mercedes-Platz 1 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain"     ,
2023-05-26 ,Hans Zimmer Live ,Europe Tour 2023                              ,Germany ,Berlin ,Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin ,"Mercedes-Platz 1, 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain"    ,
2023-07-07 ,Depeche Mode     ,Memento Mori World Tour 2023                  ,Germany ,Berlin ,Olympiastadion Berlin      ,"Olympischer Platz 3, 14053 Berlin-Charlottenburg" ,

the data is correctly read and written to the table
mysql> select * from concerts2;
+----+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| id | Date       | Band             | ConcertName                                   | Country | City   | Location                   | LocationAddress                                  |
+----+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 2023-05-28 | Ozzy Osbourne    | No More Tours 2 - Special Guest: Judas Priest | Germany | Berlin | Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin | Mercedes-Platz 1, 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain    |
|  2 | 2023-05-08 | Elton John       | Farewell Yellow Brick Road Tour 2023          | Germany | Berlin | Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin | Mercedes-Platz 1 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain     |
|  3 | 2023-05-26 | Hans Zimmer Live | Europe Tour 2023                              | Germany | Berlin | Mercedes-Benz Arena Berlin | Mercedes-Platz 1, 10243 Berlin-Friedrichshain    |
|  4 | 2023-07-07 | Depeche Mode     | Memento Mori World Tour 2023                  | Germany | Berlin | Olympiastadion Berlin      | Olympischer Platz 3, 14053 Berlin-Charlottenburg |
+----+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+

How can I modify my query to properly read data from the original .csv file, without the trailing commas in it.
I cannot modify the original .csv file. the solution must be a sql query or a change in mysql's settings/config

Apparently your CSV file has lines that are not terminated by \n. Have you opened it in a hex editor or a text editor that will show non-printable characters (like Notepad++)?

Yes I checked and the lines were being terminated by \r\n. It's working now, Thanks for the help.

The issue with commas appearing in your upload possibly stems from the incorrect handling of fields that include commas within them. When you specify FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' (or don't specify the enclosing character correctly), MySQL doesn't properly handle fields that contain commas but are enclosed in quotes. These commas are misinterpreted as field delimiters, which causes the fields to be split incorrectly.
Try changing:
ENCLOSED BY '"'

to:
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'


I've tried this too, but the problem is still there
